# How can I send a C-g/quit signal to emacs from within emacsclient when the server is busy?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacsclient

In my current setup, I run `emacs --daemon` on boot and thereafter use `emacsclient` to do work. However, I've noticed a problem with this. When a complex chunk of processing is happening, <kbd>C-g</kbd> stops working: the complex work can't be halted or terminated early. As far as I can tell, this is because an emacs client needs to wait to be acknowledged by the server before any input from the client is processed. As a result, <kbd>C-g</kbd> won't work when I most need it - to bail out of processes that are time-consuming or possibly destructive.

Are there any workarounds to this, or a way to tell the server process "stop that!"? Nothing in the [Quitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html) or [Emergency Escape](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emergency-Escape.html) sections of the manual seems to acknowledge that this problem exists - so it's also possible that this is the result of me doing something wrong. If so, what am I doing wrong?

If the answer is "no, there is no way to do what you want; `emacsclient` processes can't cope with the server being blocked for a nontrivial amount of time," I'll mark as accepted the answer that points out in code or documention where that answer can be had: I haven't been able to find such a thing. :(

Comment: I don't think that "run a regular emacs session and turn it into a server" is a good answer: the problems with that are why I switched to using `emacs --daemon` and `emacsclient` in the first place. "Don't get into situations like that" is equivalent to "don't make mistakes" and is a non-answer.

Comment: What sort of "complex chunk of processing" is the server process doing?

Comment: @event_jr: Along the lines of `(mapcar (run a shell script that takes 10 seconds) *list-from-SQL-query*)`. The query isn't useful if I put a LIMIT clause on it that takes it below ~15 results, and the non-LIMIT version I accidentally ran took most of an hour (10s times a few hundred results). I'm trying to make the individual parts more efficient, but it would also improve matters quite a lot if I could bail out of executions once it becomes apparent that they're not working.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  I think it would be an excellent question for the [emacs.se] Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Please file your problem as a bug report (providing enough details that someone can try to reproduce the problem).  Most likely the problem is that `inhibit-quit` is bound somewhere that gets in the way.

Answer (score 6):

So far the only way I found ever working is to send a `SIGUSR2` signal to the busy emacs process using command line `kill` -- no matter if it's running as a server (with `--daemon`) or not. This will not force terminating the emacs process while being able to interrupt what it's doing. Let's try an example to break a `sleep-for` loop running on emacs server. (Yes, `sleep-for` can be break by `C-g` but this is just an example. It worked on *some* cases when emacs does not respond to keyboard commands.)

First, start emacs server then use `emacsclient` connect to it, enter `M-: (sleep-for 120)`. Now go to another terminal and find the process ID of the server using command line: `ps x|grep 'emacs.*--daemon'`. Assuming the PID we found here is 12345. Now use the terminal to break it:

`kill -USR2 12345`

We should now see the `sleep-for` loop interrupted. On some cases I need to send this signal multiple times.

Also notice that `SIGUSR1` does not work so `SIGUSR2` is recommended, and this might only work on Emacs versions greater than v24. Hope this helps!

Comment: Years from the original question, I am now in a better place to appreciate this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. [(emacs) Checklist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Checklist.html) also mentions that Emacs responses the `SIGUSR2` signal.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an elegant solution. One possibility is to create a spare emacsclient session tucked away in a tmux/screen session that you can bring back up and then punch in C-g there.  But that's kind of gross.

Comment: If I understand you right, I tried that and it didn't work. :( I have several emacsclient instances open, and when the server is grinding away on something difficult, they all stop responding.